# Import maven project but parent module disabled

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, pom.xml

I would like to import this project in my ecplise workspace:
https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-example

structure of the project is:

1. gwt-maven-example-master

   - pom.xml
   - server

     - pom.xml
     - ...
   - shared

     - pom.xml
     - ...
   - web

     - pom.xml
     - ...

parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.hpfsc</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>server</module>
        <module>shared</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <gwtVersion>2.5.0</gwtVersion>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tomcat.webport>8082</tomcat.webport>
        <tomcat.ajpport>8182</tomcat.ajpport>
        <tomcat.context>/parent</tomcat.context>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0-rc2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>${tomcat.context}</path>
                    <port>${tomcat.webport}</port>
                    <ajpPort>${tomcat.ajpport}</ajpPort>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <JAVA_OPTS>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</JAVA_OPTS>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I try to import the folder containing this pom into eclipse, it allows me to select the children folder but not the parent itself.

Why can't import the parent pom?
I've tried to create a parent folder, put the pom.xml inside and reference other modules using ../server and it doesn't work.
I've tried to remove the code related to the tomcat configuration from the parent pom and it doesn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: How do you try to import the projects? Do you have the m2e plugin installed? What eclipse version do you use? (And, welcome!)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the m2e plugin installed (you may already have this depending on the version of eclipse). I guess at the moment you are doing "import" then "Existing Projects into Workspace", but instead you need to select "Existing Maven Projects". This will allow you to select the parent pom and also the child modules.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. M2e is installed, and I'm doing import existing maven project. The thing is that the server/pom.xml shared/pom.xml and web/pom.xml can be selected but the /pom.xml is disabled and can't be selected

Comment: When you click on the disabled parent pom, eclipse usually shows an message telling you why it's disabled e.g. "project already imported into workspace". Also, I've just tried it and it works fine for me in Eclipse Indigo SR2 with m2e 1.0.200. Try running `mvn clean install` on the parent to check the whole project builds correctly.